# How to add rows with a for loop with main rows and sub rows in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have some number of groups with different number of members, like

```
group_1
  -member1
  -member2
  -member3
  -member5
group_2
  -member4
  -member6
  -member6
group_2
  -member7
```

So, I want to get a table from the database, and the other thing is some number of branches have groups. I want to get a table when I select a branch, then as a main row group name and as a child, row member details.

I tried implementing this using JavaScript for loops, but the result is that it first prints all the groups and then all the members, like this:

```
if (number_of_groups != 0) {
    var max_sub_row = 0;
    for (var ig = 1; ig <= number_of_groups; ig++) {
        var head = head_row + 1;
        var markup = '<tr id="group_' + ig + '"><td colspan="20" >Group No: ' + ig + '</td></tr>';
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/getgroupmembers.php',·
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                branch_id: id,
                group_id: ig
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                    var sub_markup = '<tr id="sub_'+'_'ig'_' + i+ '"><td colspan="10" > ' + res.data[i] + '</td><td colspan="10" > ' + res.data1[i] + '</td></tr>';
                    $("table tbody").append(sub_markup);
                }//sub for
                max_sub_row = res.data.length;
            }
        });
    } //for
} //if number_of_groups
[this is image for result][1]
```

Comment: $.ajax is an asynchronous function. You tell call it now, but don't wait for the answer. The answer might come some time in the distant future. You also make a network request for every group. Every network request have overhead and takes a very long time. I suggest that you rewrite your code and assemble the data in your php script, and then send all data at once to the javascript function. That will make your application at least 1000 faster and less complicated.

Comment: Use async await with promises instead

Comment: got it and I'm trying to edit my PHP code to solve the problem.